# Post multipart form with multiple file uploads using python requests

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, multipartform-data

I have demographics information extracted for some people in the form of list of python dictionaries(each dict for an individual). Also I need to upload the document from where I extracted the data (pdf/word). I tried Multipart form submission using Python requests which because of some reason does not seem to work.

The API expects two keys 'files' and 'data'
'files' is a list of file objects 
'data' is a list of dicts which is stringified using json.dumps (API requirements)

```
pay_part= [{"umr":"","age":"","gender":"","first_name":"","middle_name":"","last_name":"","phone":"","address":"","admission_date":"","lab":"","discharge_date":"","ip_number":"","diagnosis":"","reason":"","treatment":"","medications":"","expired_date":"","instructions":"","review_date":"","procedure":"","notes":"","physician":"","filename":""},{"umr":"","age":"","gender":"","first_name":"","middle_name":"","last_name":"","phone":"","address":"","admission_date":"","lab":"","discharge_date":"","ip_number":"","diagnosis":"","reason":"","treatment":"","medications":"","expired_date":"","instructions":"","review_date":"","procedure":"","notes":"","physician":"","filename":""}]

multipart_data = MultipartEncoder(
fields={
        "file":[('file.docx',open('13427.docx', 'rb'),'text/plain'), 
        ('file.docx',open('13427.docx', 'rb'),'text/plain')],
         "payload": json.dumps(pay_part)
        }
                                  )

response = requests.post(url, data=multipart_data, headers={'Content-Type': 'multipart_data.content_type; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW', 'userid': sUserID,'metaid': metaid,'postman-token':postmanToken})
print(response.text)
```

While forming the multipart form object I get an error 
"AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'".

I believe this has to do something with creating file objects as a binary and storing in list.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it to work!

Just send your json object using the argument ‘data’ and a list of your file objects using the argument ‘files’ as shown below.

I removed from the header argument “'Content-Type': 'multipart_data.content_type; boundary=---WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW'”

The post request was made as a multipart post

Code:-

```
fields={'payload': json.dumps(pay_part)})

response = requests.post(url, data=fields,files =[('file',open('13385.docx', 'rb')),('file',open('13385.docx', 'rb'))],  headers={'userid': sUserID,'metaid': metaid,'postman-token':postmanToken})
print(response.text)
```